# Application.ProcessMessages in a TThread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

is it "OK" to call `Application.Processmessages` inside a Thread (not Main-Thread) or should I expect troubles?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to do that, the fact you are asking this question is a sign you are doing something the wrong way. Treat the disease, not the symptoms...

Comment: My Threads might using shared procedures that implement application.processmessages in their loops, as they have been used in single-threaded code. Resuing those procedures inside a thread does cause problems or  not?

Comment: well the point of multithreading is to offload GUI blocking tasks off the main thread, hence Application.Processmessages would no longer be needed, got my point?

Comment: Yes, but the question was not if it is NEEDED or USEFUL, but simple if it is "OK" (e.g. not hurting) to have it there. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but it seems you've already got your answer, Application.Processmessages is evil in some contexts and can lead to unpredictable behaviour,...

Comment: Calling Application.Processmessage from a thread won't just process messages... It will also create a message queue for said thread. Once a thread has created a message queue, it is REQUIRED that messages sent to that queue be processed in a timely manner. Not doing so has, amongs other thing, performance impact on the system where the application is running.

Comment: @KenBourassa Application.ProcessMessages will not create message queue. Message queue is automatically created for thread if you create window handle in that thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar And, from your very own link, it is also created if a thread "perform operations which require a message queue". That includes PeekMessage that is called by Application.ProcessMessages. So ProcessMessages WILL create the message queue if none exists, which isn't all that unlikely in the context of the question.

Comment: @KenBourassa I might interpret that sentence in wrong way, but the next sentence mentions window handle, not a PeekMessage. And at least on Windows 10 and Delphi 10.4 calling Application.ProcessMessages in a thread does not create message queue, while creating window does.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The next sentence mention if the thread creates one or more windows, the thread need to have a message loop (IOW, it needs to pump messages). And I don't know about Delphi 10.4, but with Seattle/Win10.20H2, ProcessMessages does create the message queue. Simply calling PeekMessage once creates the message queue.

Comment: @KenBourassa I messed up my test example. You are correct. PeekMessage creates message queue, but this is not mentioned in PeekMessage docs, rather in PostThreadMessage docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea A bit less ambiguity in docs would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `Application.ProcessMessages` from a thread other that main thread is really a bad idea because it is really aimed at VCL and VCL is not thread safe.

This being said, I have a lot of threads having a `message loop` so that it handle cooperative multitasking and inter-thread communication.

I always write my own message loop by calling Windows API:

```
while GetMessage(MsgRec, 0, 0, 0) do begin
    TranslateMessage(MsgRec);
    DispatchMessage(MsgRec)
end;
```

I make an heavy use of this in my ICS (Internet Component Suite) when an asynchronous TWSocket has to run in a thread. The code above is part of ICS in TIcsWndControl. TWSocket can easily handle hundreds of connection per thread but if you want to handle thousands of connections, you have to use threads.

Using Windows messages between worker threads or main thread and worker thread is often a solution to avoid calling `TThread.Synchronize`: When you PostMessage from a thread, the sending thread continue to run and the receiving thread (the one which created the window handle passed in PostMessage) will gracefully handle the message in his own context.

Comment: Note that by default Windows NT has a limit of 10,000 posted (unprocessed) messages per message queue. Can be increased but really at that point other methods should be locked at (often post a notification and the main thread then grabs multiple work items/etc).  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew

Answer (score 8):

`TApplication.ProcessMessages()` is designed primarily to process VCL messages.  You should not be receiving any VCL messages in a worker thread, unless you are creating and displaying `TForm` windows from worker threads.  Which you should not be doing, since the VCL is not thread-safe and should not be used outside of the main UI thread.

But, that being said, if no VCL messages are received in a worker thread, calling `ProcessMessages()` in a worker thread is not itself harmful. It will dispatch any received messages (VCL or otherwise) to the appropriate window procedure in the calling thread.  But, if you think you need manual message dispatching in a worker thread, you really need to question why you need that in the first place.  Unless you are using COM apartment-threaded objects in worker threads, or posting custom thread messages to worker threads, there is very little use for running a message loop in a worker thread, and even then `ProcessMessages()` is not ideal for that purpose.

Comment: Saying that ProcessMessages is not harmful in itself isn't entirely true.  If the thread doesn't have message loop, calling ProcessMessages will create a message queue for the thread. If ProcessMessages is called just once in a while, it will lead the OS to consider the thread as being unresponsive. For example, it will make DDE call absurdly slow (which office apps still used last I checked). So, ProcessMessages will most likely be harmful if the thread doesn't have a dedicated message loop.

Comment: TApplication.ProcessMessages is not thread safe because it does more than simply pumping the message queue. It can only be safely called from the context of the main thread.